# IoT Hub iothubconnection may not function properly because it is not in an ACTIVE state

Tags: subscription, azure-iot-hub

I created a subscription in my azure account and for 2 months ago it's always inactive.

I have this message :IoT Hub may not function properly because it is not in an ACTIVE state.
The status is "suspended", in the Portal main page the subscription is "Disabled". Please find attached the screenshots showing the current behavior.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to delete and create the IoT Hub again?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Azure has caching issue if you delete an IoTHub (or any other type of resource) and then create another one with the same name.

I had the same problem, it was even showing the metrics from the old one on the new one!
to fix it, delete the old one then wait a few hours to create a new one.

If you didn't delete one, just wait a few hours and it should get fixed automatically.